# Scraping links with BeautifulSoup from all pages in Amazon results in error

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to scrape product URLs from the Amazon Webshop, by going through every page.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64;     x64; rv:66.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/66.0", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate",     "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}

products = set()
for i in range(1, 21):
    url = 'https://www.amazon.fr/s?k=phone%2Bcase&page=' + str(i)
    response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)

    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content)

    print(soup) # prints the HTML content saying Error on Amazon's side

    links = soup.select('a.a-link-normal.a-text-normal')

    for tag in links:
        url_product = 'https://www.amazon.fr' + tag.attrs['href']
        products.add(url_product)
```

Instead of getting the content of the page, I get a *"Sorry, something went wrong on our end"*  HTML Error Page. What is the reason behind this? How can I successfully bypass this error and scrape the products?

Comment: Check my answer below, let me know if you need further help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to your question:

Be informed that `AMAZON` not allowing automated access to for it's data! So you can double check this by checking the response via `r.status_code` ! which can lead you to have that error MSG:

```
To discuss automated access to Amazon data please contact api-services-support@amazon.com
```

Therefore you can use `AMAZON API` or you can pass a list of `proxies` to the GET request via `proxies = list_proxies`.

Here's the correct way to pass `headers` to `Amazon` without getting block and it's Works.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

headers = {
    'Host': 'www.amazon.fr',
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:70.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/70.0',
    'Accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language': 'en-US,en;q=0.5',
    'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'Connection': 'keep-alive',
    'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests': '1',
    'TE': 'Trailers'
}

for item in range(1, 21):
    r = requests.get(
        'https://www.amazon.fr/s?k=phone+case&page={item}&ref=sr_pg_{item}', headers=headers)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
    for item in soup.findAll('a', attrs={'class': 'a-link-normal a-text-normal'}):
        print(f"https://www.amazon.fr{item.get('href')}")
```

Run Online: [Click Here](https://repl.it/@AmericanY/Amazon)

Comment: Thanks, this seems to be working. The only changes I see are the `'Connection': 'keep-alive'` and `'TE': 'Trailers'`. what does `'TE': 'Trailers'` do?

Comment: @Snow it's mean `Transfer Encoding` check here to understand https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/TE

Comment: your headers saved me, thank you. Headers suck