# Web scraping using python not working both for Amazon and Monster

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I try to learn Web Scraping using python. 1st I try to scrape from an amazon page. I try to find out the Best Sellers in Women's Fashion Sneakers.

My code:

no_pages = 2

```
def get_data(pageNo):  
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
    r = requests.get('https://www.amazon.com/Best-Sellers-Womens-Fashion-Sneakers/zgbs/fashion/679394011'+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo), headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    print(soup)
```

I did not get any output for this portion. Then I find out [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59086588/scraping-links-with-beautifulsoup-from-all-pages-in-amazon-results-in-error). I thought that web scraping is not possible for Amazon. Then I changed my source page to monster.com. But did not get the output.

```
no_pages = 2

def get_data(pageNo):  
    headers = {"User-Agent":"Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.182 Safari/537.36", "Accept-Encoding":"gzip, deflate", "Accept":"text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8", "DNT":"1","Connection":"close", "Upgrade-Insecure-Requests":"1"}
    r = requests.get('https://www.monster.com/jobs/search/?q=Software-developer&where=Texas-City__2C-TX'+str(pageNo)+'?ie=UTF8&pg='+str(pageNo), headers=headers)#, proxies=proxies)
    content = r.content
    soup = BeautifulSoup(content)
    print(soup)
```

How could I solve this problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that your code runs correctly. However, you need to call the function in order to run it. For instance, after your function, write the following:

```
    get_data(no_pages)
```

This will trigger the function to run.

Comment: Adding `get_data(no_pages)` does not change anything.

Comment: This must be added outside of the function.

Comment: Okay, So it's working both amazon and monster. Thanks

Comment: If that is the case, please accept the answer so that this question can be considered answered.